# How to display Hidden field value in Paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display hiddentfield value in

```
 <p style="color: Red">
    Please note that you have <span>
       javascript:$("input[id$=hdnCartCount]").val();
   </span> more pending orders.
     <br />
      Click Checkout to proceed!
 </p>
```

How can I display?

Comment: Populate the paragraph tag the same way as you populate the hidden field

Comment: You could start by putting your javascript in a `<script>` tag. which suggests you don't understand javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want this to be dynamic, slight re-arrange your HTML (**note the ID I've given to your span**):

```
 <p style="color: Red">
    Please note that you have 
    <span id="pendingOrdersCount"></span> 
    more pending orders.
    <br />
    Click Checkout to proceed!
 </p>
```

Then you can do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#pendingOrdersCount").text($("input[id$=hdnCartCount]").val());
});

</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25xQn/)

Comment: don't forget the `<script>` tag, a bit of hand holding may be in need here! :)

Comment: @mattytommo - inline style.  Euuurgh!

Answer (score 0):

Try giving an **id to the span** and

```
$("#spanId").text($('#hdnField').val());
```